# How can I get the last element of an array inside of my fetchall_arrayref foreach loop in Perl?

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm using Perl with MySql.  I have query that I'm using with fetchall_arrayref to grab results data from my survey application.  As recommended by documentation I use foreach to loop through fetchall_arrayref.  Inside of this loop, I loop through my $answer1 data and run a counter to count all of the answers for a question and I want the total.  When I push this information into an array and try to grab the last element in that array, I don't get the desired output.  I ran a test outside of my fetchall_arrayref foreach loop, using the same logic and it was successful in getting me what I needed.

Here's my code:

```
my $testQuery = "SELECT questionNum, question, answer1 FROM results WHERE title = ? ORDER BY questionNum";
my $sty = $dbh->prepare($testQuery);
$sty->execute($marathon);
my $potential = $sty->fetchall_arrayref();
$sty->finish;

my $previous_question;
my $previous_answer;
my $countEm;
my @total;
my @totalAnswer;
my @norm;
my $last_arr_index;
foreach my $data (@$potential) {
    my ($questionNumber, $question, $answer1) = @$data;
    $answeredOne = 0;
    print qq{<tr><td>$questionNumber. $question</td></tr>} unless $previous_question eq $question;
    if ($answer1 ne "" && $questionNumber == 1){
        $optionOne = $answer1;
        $answeredOne = $answeredOne + 1;
        $countEm++;
        push @total, $countEm;
        push @totalAnswer, $optionOne;
    }
    if ($answeredOne != 0){
        #my $elementCount = scalar(@total);
        #say $elementCount;
        say @total[-1];
    }

$previous_question = $question;
$previous_answer = @totalAnswer[2];
}#end foreach
```

When I print: "say @total[-1];" gives me the output of "1 2 3" when I just need "3".

I tested this same logic outside of the fetchall_arrayref foreach loop and I got the desired output:

```
my $counting;
my @totalCounting;
my @link = ('water', 'water', 'water', 'water', 'water');
foreach my $i (@link){
    $counting++;
    push @totalCounting, $counting;
}
say @totalCounting[-1];
```

"say totalCounting[-1];" gives me "5".

Why won't this work inside of fetchall_arrayref?

Comment: In one case, you print total in a loop. In the other case, you don't If you only want to do it once, don't put it in a loop!

Comment: The whole idea of using `@total` is flawed. The final count is what you want, and that's already in `$countEm`

Comment: When you interpolate arrays into a string with `"@foo"` it will join the values with spaces (actually, `$,`). You're not doing that here, but you should be seeing the last value `3` and a warning that it should be written `$total[-1]`.

Comment: @ikegami I use "@total" because I couldn't get the last element (3) out of $countEm.  Is there another way to get the last number of $countEm without putting them in a array?

Comment: @simbabque Hey.  I also tried $total[-1] and I still get:  1 2 3 printed.  I don't understand.

Comment: I have been informed that I am getting 1 2 3 because I have printed inside of the fetchall_arrayref foreach loop.  Printing outside of this loop will give me 3 but I need to print inside of the loop because all of my data is connected and I'm able to make conditionals when printing.  Is there a way to get the single last element inside of the fetchall_arrayref?

Comment: Re "*to get the last number of $countEm without putting them in a array?*", `$countEm` is always equal to `@total[-1]`. You simply have to use `$countEm` instead of `@total[-1]`

Comment: @ikegami What you're saying makes sense to me but when I print $countEm inside of my fetchall_arrayref foreach loop, I get 1 2 3 instead of just 3.

Comment: And that's what you get from `@total[-1]`. So it's exactly like I said: There's absolutely no difference between `$countEm` and `@total[-1]`

Comment: Note that unless you plan on using `$potential` outside the loop, you should use `while(my $data = $sty->fetch)`. This reads one row at a time and avoids slurping a potentially very large number of rows into memory.

Comment: If you have updates or clarifications, update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet is equivalent to

```perl
my $counting;
my @totalCounting;
my @link = ('water', 'water', 'water', 'water', 'water');
foreach my $i (@link){
    $counting++;
    push @totalCounting, $counting;
    say @totalCounting[-1];
}
```

If you want to do something after the loop, place it after the loop and not in it where it will get executed multiple times.

---

The whole concept of using an array to only use its last element is flawed. Simpler and last wasteful:

```perl
my @link = ('water', 'water', 'water', 'water', 'water');

my $counting;
for my $i (@link) {
    $counting++;
}

say $counting;
```

(Of course, you could simply use `say 0+@link;` here, but it's understood this code is a proxy for a larger snippet where the counting is conditional.)

---

> *Is there a way to get the single last element inside of the fetchall_arrayref?*

`$total[-1]` (and thus `@total[-1]`) *is* the single last element of `@total`.

Well, it's the last element as it currently exists. You obviously can't get an element you haven't placed in `@total` yet. But that's exactly what it sounds like you want to to do. If you need the total before the loop is done, you will need to calculate it before you need it.

```perl
my $total;
for my $data (@$potential) {
    my ($questionNumber, $question, $answer1) = @$data;
    if ($answer1 ne "" && $questionNumber == 1) {
        $total++;
    }
}

for my $data (@$potential) {
    my ($questionNumber, $question, $answer1) = @$data;
    # Do something that uses $total...
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now.  Thank you for drawing it out.  $answer1 is one of 10, $answer10 being the highest In a program that needs results for questions with no limit.  So I may have to do this potentially 10 times per question for numerous questions.  I feel like this could get messy.  Is there a cleaner way to get a total of variables from the database based on certain conditions in Perl?

Comment: I think you're looking for `++$totals[$question_num]` or `++$totals{$question_num}`

Comment: If so, then yes, you can have the database do that for you using `GROUP BY` and `SUM`. And it would be faster too. Feel free to ask a question about that, but be clear about what your data looks like and what you want from it.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this all though before this I tried using GROUP BY.  I should have included more information.  The reason why GROUP BY didn't work is because for some questions, there are checkbox answers with multiple answers and GROUP BY would put them together.  Ex.
1. How is your day?
good
bad
okay

using GROUP BY on my results page will display:
1. How is your day?
good: 4
good/bad: 3
bad :3

When I need a complete total of each answer, no combinations.

So instead I need good to be:  good: 7 instead of split up between both options.

Comment: Also, I tried to upvote you but I'm too new here for it to matter.

Comment: (I meant `COUNT`. not `SUM`)

Comment: That's not true, of you group on a field, if will group the rows with identical values for that field only `SELECT questionNumber, answer, COUNT(*) GROUP BY questionNumber, answer` if you want the count of each answer a question has, or `SELECT questionNumber, COUNT(*) GROUP BY questionNumber` if you want the count of answers each question has.

Comment: pardon me as I just painfully wrote all of this out trying to get the correct output, before seeing your edit.
 `my $queryQuery = "SELECT questionNum, question, answer1, COUNT(answer1), answer2, COUNT(answer2), answer3, COUNT(answer3), answer4, COUNT(answer4), answer5, COU        NT(answer5), answer6, COUNT(answer6), answer7, COUNT(answer7), answer8, COUNT(answer8), answer9, COUNT(answer9), answer10, COUNT(answer10) FROM results WHERE title = ? GROUP BY questionNum, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10 ORDER BY questionNum";`

Comment: That schema makes no sense, and it's actively getting in the way of what you want to do.

Comment: I now realize this was my problem when I tried to use GROUP BY.  I thought I understood what I read about GROUP BY.
When doing it your way using COUNT(*) I wasn't clear on how to assign those counts to a variable.
I split them up because then I could do 
`while(my($answer1, $answerCount1, $answer2, $answerCount2) = $sty->fetchrow_array)`

Comment: But that prevents you from doing `++$totals[$question_num]`, requiring extensive code in its place.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness in going back and fourth with me until I understand.  You've gone above and beyond my expectations of the posts I usually read here.  Thank you.

Comment: So if I add all of my answer columns to my query and COUNT(*) , I can get the desired output.  I assign COUNT to $totals?
`SELECT questionNum, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, COUNT(*) GROUP BY questionNum, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10 ORDER BY questionNum`
exclude question from GROUP BY?
also when I go to declare my variables, I declare COUNT(*) or is it now a built in function?