# How can I count and group columns separately with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a survey application and I'm working on the results page. For each question, the page should display the different answers provided and how many times each was provided.

Some questions can accept multiple answers. For example, let's assume the following is one such question:

1. How are you feeling?

- Good
- Bad
- Okay

This means that any combination of `Good`, `Bad` and/or `Okay` are allowed as an answer.

Say the responses from the survey are the following:

- Survey 1: `Good`, `Bad` and `Okay`
- Survey 2: `Good`, `Bad` and `Okay`
- Survey 3: `Good` and `Bad`
- Survey 4: `Good` and `Bad`
- Survey 5: `Good`
- Survey 6: `Good`
- Survey 7: `Good`

The following is the expected result:

1. How are you feeling?

- Good = 7
- Bad = 4
- Okay = 2

My code delivers

1. How are you feeling?

- Good = 3
- Bad = 2
- Good = 4
- Okay = 1
- Bad = 2
- Okay = 1

The database entries for this example look like this:

| questionNum | question | answer1 | answer2 | answer3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | How are you feeling? | Good | Bad | Okay |  |
| 1 | How are you feeling? | Good | Bad | Okay |  |
| 1 | How are you feeling? | Good | Bad |  |  |
| 1 | How are you feeling? | Good | Bad |  |  |
| 1 | How are you feeling? | Good |  |  |  |
| 1 | How are you feeling? | Good |  |  |  |
| 1 | How are you feeling? | Good |  |  |  |

Here's my code:

```
my $queryQuery = "SELECT questionNum, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, COUNT(*) FROM results WHERE title = ? GROUP BY answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10 ORDER BY questionNum";
my $sthm = $dbh->prepare($queryQuery);
$sthm->execute($marathon);

my $prev_question;
while(my($questNumber, $quest, $ans1, $ans2, $ans3, $ans4, $ans5, $ans6, $ans7, $ans8, $ans9, $ans10, $count) = $sthm->fetchrow_array){
print qq{<tr><td> $questNumber. $quest \n </td></tr>} unless $quest eq $prev_question; # the trailing conditional is to get rid of the duplicate questions that print out.
print qq{<tr><td> $ans1 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans1 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans2 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans2 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans3 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans3 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans4 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans4 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans5 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans5 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans6 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans6 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans7 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans7 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans8 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans8 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans9 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans9 eq "";
print qq{<tr><td> $ans10 = $count </td></tr>} unless $ans10 eq "";
$prev_question = $quest;
}
```

Here I am looping through the query to print out all of the questions with no duplicates and print the answers with the questions as long as they aren't empty.  Here is where I'm searching for the output described above as 1. How are you feeling? Good = 7, Bad = 4, Okay = 2.
Instead I'm getting the answers divided into groups because the user has selected multiple answers for a single question with check boxes instead of radiobuttons.  So inside of the database it appears that even though the answers have been put into their own columns they are connected because they were entered at the same time by the user selecting to options for the question.

Comment: First fix your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, **describe your data clearly**. I still have no idea what it is, and you didn't even attempt to describe it

Comment: @ikegami I didn't proof the format of the code printed that's on me.  Is this any better?  I'm happy to clear anything else up.

Comment: @Strawberry I should have looked harder before submitting, my mistake.  How's this look?  I'll be happy to clear anything else up.

Comment: Although some questions might take multiple answers, using an example that has mutually exclusive options is very confusing. Your example question should have only one answer. A better example might be something like "Which pets do you have? a) dog b)cat c)bird d) none".

Answer (score 2):

I know you are struggling with many things at the same time, but the the best answer solves the problem that [ikegami quickly passed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773608/2766176) over on his way to doing it in Perl:

> That's a horrible database schema.

People often do much more than they need to at the application level because they never learn to do the right things in the database (such as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66768033/2766176) which is better answered by an appropriate SQL query instead of Perl). But, as an aside, many people do that because they are unable to change the schema. Social heuristics, such as the appropriate application of beer, sometimes smooths that path. A little work convincing the database people pays off in multiples later. And, as another aside, "full stack developer" often omits any sophisticated use of databases.

I'm not going to make anyone read C.J. Date's *Database in Depth*, but there is a lot of value in getting the schema right. By right, I mean that it imposes the least amount of effort and complexity on its use. Things should be easy, and you shouldn't have to rearrange these things at the application level.

You want to count the number of times each answer is selected. Counting is something that databases do very well, so let the database do it.

You have some questions. Questions have various answers. Surveys group together sets of questions. People respond to surveys by associating their answers with the questions.

Here's a simple schema design (and some database guy will eventually show up and tell me I didn't do it right, but that's fine). The trick is that nothing has to have multiple columns that are unused. Everything comes in a neat little package (the "relation" in "relational database") that's easily connected to the other things through "foreign keys" (e.g. question_id to map an answer to the question). Answers, for examples, will have multiple rows for the same `question_id`.

If someone wants to come in with the fancy modeling tools and make the picture, go for it. I'm marking this as community wiki.

```
Table: Questions
   id
   text

Table: Answers
   id
   text
   question_id

Table: Surveys
   id 
   title

Table: SurveyQuestionSet
   id
   survey_id
   question_id   

Table: Respondent
   id
   text

Table: Response
   id
   respondent_id
   survey_id
   question_id
   answer_id
```

Once mapped out and normalized properly (read up on [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)), it's very easy to get the data you want with SELECTs. The ideal of normalize is simply to not repeat information or allow it to get into an inconsistent state. In these forms, many things become much easier to do.

And, if you want to practice such things, the [Stackoverflow Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) is a real-life data set normalized to what I've presented here.

Now you simply count the number of times `answer_id` shows up for a particular  combination of survey and question. Slick use of `GROUP BY` does all the work for you. You no longer need to iterate through rows looking at tens of unused columns trying to figure out how to count them. Not only that, but you can make these things [views](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx/), which means you write the query once and the database pretends its results are a table. You can then simply query the view (so all the `JOIN`s and likewise are hidden), which is much simple. Stored procedures are also often overlooked.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer.  I'm quite new to programming and new to Perl.  I appreciate all of the included links.  I have very little database experience as you can tell.  I have a lot of reading to do and most of it comes from not knowing what I don't know.  I'm here to stay and I don't mind reading documentation as it will make me a better programmer.  I will continue to rework this code until I get it right.
ps.  I hope you receive this notification.  I tried to "@" you but you have spaces in your user name and I don't know if that was the proper way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform your (awful) data model into something that is more useful. This is the sort of fiddling you will need to perform to get the result you are looking for.

```
select questionNum ,question ,answer, count(*) as num_of
from (
  select questionNum ,question ,answer1 as answer FROM results where answer1 IS NOT NULL union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer2 as answer FROM results where answer2 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer3 as answer FROM results where answer3 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer4 as answer FROM results where answer4 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer5 as answer FROM results where answer5 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer6 as answer FROM results where answer6 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer7 as answer FROM results where answer7 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer8 as answer FROM results where answer8 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer9 as answer FROM results where answer9 IS NOT NULL  union all
  select questionNum ,question ,answer10 as answer FROM results where answer10 IS NOT NULL
  ) as fiddle
group by  questionNum ,question ,answer
```

To avoid fiddles of this nature in future you really ought to consider re-arranging the table. What tends to happen with this is that the fiddles get exponentially harder to create over time. so please do take some time to reconsider your data model.

Comment: Thank you.  I am in the process of sharpening my database skills.

Answer (score 1):

That's a horrible database schema.

This will be a lot easier to do in Perl.

```perl
my %counts_by_answer_by_qid;
{
   my $sql = '
      SELECT `questionNum`,
             `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `answer5`,
             `answer6`, `answer7`, `answer8`, `answer9`, `answer10`
        FROM `results`
       WHERE `title` = ?
   ';

   my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute($title);

   while ( my ($questionNum, @answers) = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
      ++$counts_by_answer_by_qid{$questionNum}{$_} for grep length, @answers;
   }
}

{
   my $sql = '
      SELECT DISTINCT
             `questionNum`,
             `question`
        FROM `results`
       WHERE `title` = ?
       ORDER BY `questionNum`
   ';

   my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute($title); 

   while ( my ($questionNum, $question) = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
      my $counts_by_answer = $counts_by_answer_by_qid{$questionNum} // {};
      say "$questionNum. $question";

      for my $answer (
         sort { $counts_by_answer->{$b} <=> $counts_by_answer->{$a} }
            keys(%$counts_by_answer)
      ) {
         my $count = $counts_by_answer->{$answer};
         say "* $answer = $count";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm reading through your code now to make sure that I understand it.  I assume that although even though the sql query both have the same name $sql that they are diff query with diff statement handles?  Or are you just declaring them again after each use?

Comment: New vars that only exist within the curlies in which they are declared

Comment: Also the very first bracket "{" and the very last bracket "}".  Are these used for the purpose of stackoverflow or is this also code?  My apologies I'm new here and fairly new to Perl.  I see that all loops are opened and closed and these appear to be extra.
And in the last while loop,  second line where you're declaring $counts_by_answer.  I see $question_id as a new variable.  Was this meant to be there?  I didn't see where it was declared before with "my".

Comment: Okay.  Thanks again!

Comment: Fixed the missing prepare+execute. Fixed `$question_id` vs `$questionNum`. Those curlies the scope of each `$sql` and `$sth`

Comment: Thank you!  I will test this out.  One more thing I spotted and it could be nothing as I'm not familiar with this part of the code.  In the same line next to the $question_id vs $questionNum that you fixed.  Should {} be empty or should it be {$_} as you have in the previous line above?

Comment: That creates an empty hash and returns a ref to it. Handles questions with no answers

Comment: Thanks!  I will work with this code and let you know how well it goes.

Comment: I was getting a Global symbol "%counts_by_answer" requires explicit package at "my $count" below the for loop in the last while loop. I declared it above the for loop. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: once declared I get no errors and it prints.  The output however prints without the count of the answers.  So I'm seeing:  1. How are you feeling? Good = , Bad = , Okay = .
I will compare my code with yours to make sure that I didn't miss anything.  I'll also make a new post with updated code and output.

Comment: now that I think about it I'm sure declaring that variable is a mistake and is probably why my answer count is empty.  I don't understand why the error message was telling me %counts_by_answer requires explicit package.

Comment: Should be `$counts_by_answer->{$answer}`. Fixed

Comment: THANKS!  This worked.  Again, I will up vote you but I'm so new it appears not to matter.

Comment: Hey quick question.  How are we able to use $counts_by_answer_by_qid{$questionNum}{$_} outside of the scope of the first curlies?  I tried to do something similar in another page of code where I do this:
`my $survey_title; {
 my $sql = "SELECT title from new_survey";
my $sth =$dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
while (my ($sur_title)  =$sth->fetchrow_array) { 
$survey_title = $sur_title;
}
}
`
$sur_title doesn't print out all of the titles.  It only prints one.

Comment: $survey_title not $sur_title, my mistake.  I tried to format this the correct way even using </br> I don't know why it won't put each line on different lines.

Comment: I presume you print after that? What else would you expect from what amounts to `$survey_title ="a"; $survey_title = "b"; say $survey_title;`

Comment: I was looking to use $survey_title in the 2nd curlies just like you used $counts_by_answer_by_qid in the second curlies even though you added data to it from the first curlies.
So I want to get all of the titles, assign them to $survey_title then outside of those curlies and while loop, compare $survey_title to $title to make sure I'm not entering in any duplicates.

Comment: Re "*assign them to `$survey_title`.*", Again, assigning a value to a variable erases any value it previously had